# Building Oberver and Observable class

Tags: java, observer-pattern, observable

Instead of using built in class [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)  and [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html)  I am trying to build it myself.

From docs I figured:

```
public class Observable{
   private Set<Observer> observingMe=null;
   private boolean amIchanged;

   public void notifyObservers(Object args){
        for(Observer o:observingMe){
            o.update(args);
        }
   }

   public void addObserver(Observer e){
    observingMe.add(e);
   }

}

public class Price implements Observable{
    private int price;
    public void setPrice(int newPrice){
        price=newPrice;
        notifyObservers(price);
    }
}
public interface Observer{
    public void update(Object args);
}
```

Is this(in brief) the right implementation of Observable? What else do I need to consider while building Observable class.
Is there a way to automatically detect any chane in Observable instance or the inherited class has to explicitly call  notifyObservers?

Please don't mind the syntax or minor error

Comment: How does `Observer` look like?

Comment: updated the Observer interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your notify method, consider the case when an observer throws an exception when the update is called. If you don't handle it, it will prevent the other observers the be notified. Moreover, you may want to notify each observer in a separate thread as one of them could take a long time to react to the event, preventing the others to be notified early.

Also, you never use your boolean amIChanged and you keep it private without a getter. Otherwise, you have the basic principle implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong at first:

- `observingMe` will give a NullPointerException when used since it is not initalized.
- You cannot use `implements` with a `class`. You should use `extends` since `Observable` is a class.
- `amIchanged` is never used. You can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for notifying the mistake.But what I really wanted is to focus on the concept not code.I havn't started writing the code yet

Comment: @lliBtheLizard if you want a class like the built in Observable, why don't you read how it works?  How do you want your version to be different?

Comment: Whats wrong with trying first,asking others,analysing my mistake and then reading? It helps the community too

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the automatic observers notification: you might want to wire an AOP after advice, triggered after each `set...(...)` method invocation. (check for the exact pointcut syntax).

But is it worth the effort? To make sure method `notifyObservers()` is invoked, you might prefer a couple of test methods.

You might also consider having a `removeObserver(Observer e)` method as well.

Comment: AOP:aspect-oriented programming? Can you please explain it in a simpler manner?

Comment: Yes indeed, Aspect-oriented programming. Good introduction here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming] The AOP advice would detect each setter method invocation, and upon return trigger itself the `Observable.notifyObservers(...)` method.